# Combobox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm new to C# and I have a question which I couldn't find somehwere else.
I created a ComboBox like this:

```
ComboBox lijst = new ComboBox();
```

Also I added some items and a location:

```
lijst.Location = new Point(400, 25);

lijst.Text = "Basis";
lijst.Items.Add("Basis");
lijst.Items.Add("Zuilen");
lijst.Items.Add("Vuur");
lijst.Items.Add("Zigzag");
```

The thing is you can select a item now and press a button which triggers the next method.

```
private void bereken(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string nr = Convert.ToString(lijst.SelectedIndex);

    Label tekstuitvoer = new Label();
    tekstuitvoer.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    tekstuitvoer.Size = new Size(70, 20);
    tekstuitvoer.Text = nr;

    this.Controls.Add(tekstuitvoer);
}
```

But here is my problem. Once you press the button, the outcome of tekstuitover.Text will always be the same. So if you press the button while "Vuur" is selected then the outcome will always be 2. It doesnt matter if you change the combobox item afterwards. The output will always be 2. But when I restart the program and select the fourth option instead of the third, now the outcome always will be 3.

Can you help me with this problem? Is there a way to reset string nr?

Thanks in advance. I hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure out what you were saying there. 
Add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to your combobox, and trigger your label code from there, you can get rid of the button.

However as things stand you are going to create a new label component every time it changes.
Simpler to just add one at design time and set the text property in the event.